# Best way to write python postgres insert command

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I am a bit of a newbie and I'm stuck with this postgres insert step.

My challenge is I am pulling a Dict from a json that is stored in a list and I am trying to pull the values from the dict and save it to a postgres DB.

any help on how to write this up correctly would be appreciated

Here is the connection string for the DB under the page break line is the code used for the db insert.

```
import psycopg2

'''DATABASE CONNECTION SETTINGS'''


def dbconnect():
    """Function returns settings for db connection."""
    dbauth = psycopg2.connect("dbname='databse' user='username' \
        host='dbhost' password='password'")

    return dbauth
```

---

```
def weatherupdate(dbauth, list):

connection = dbauth

try:
    connection
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

conn = connection
cursor = conn.cursor()

l01 = list[0]['state_time_zone']
l02 = list[0]['time_zone']
l03 = list[0]['product_name']
l04 = list[0]['state']
l05 = list[0]['refresh_message']
l06 = list[0]['name']
l11 = list[1]['swell_period']
l12 = list[1]['lat']
l13 = list[1]['lon']
l14 = list[1]['cloud_oktas']
l15 = list[1]['gust_kt']
l16 = list[1]['history_product']
l17 = list[1]['local_date_time']
l18 = list[1]['cloud']
l19 = list[1]['cloud_type']
l110 = list[1]['swell_height']
l111 = list[1]['wmo']
l112 = list[1]['wind_dir']
l113 = list[1]['weather']
l114 = list[1]['wind_spd_kt']
l115 = list[1]['rain_trace']
l116 = list[1]['aifstime_utc']
l117 = list[1]['press_tend']
l118 = list[1]['press']
l119 = list[1]['vis_km']
l120 = list[1]['sea_state']
l121 = list[1]['air_temp']
l122 = list[1]['cloud_base_m']
l123 = list[1]['cloud_type_id']
l124 = list[1]['swell_dir_worded']
l125 = list[1]['sort_order']

query = "INSERT INTO weather (state_time_zone, time_zone, product_name, state, refresh_message, name, swell_period, lat, lon, cloud_oktas, gust_kt, history_product, local_date_time, cloud, cloud_type, swell_height, wmo, wind_dir, weather, wind_spd_kt, rain_trace, aifstime_utc, press_tend, press, vis_km, sea_state, air_temp, cloud_base_m, cloud_type_id, swell_dir_worded, sort_order ) VALUES (l01, l02, l03, l04, l05, l06, l11, l12, l13, l14, l15, l16, l17, l18, l19, l110, l111, l112, l113, l114, l115, l116, l117, l118, l119, l120, l121, l122, l123, l124, l125);"

cursor.execute(query)

conn.commit()
```

weatherupdate(dbconnect(), getweather())

When i run the code it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weatherDb.py", line 57, in <module>
    weatherupdate(dbconnect(), getweather())
  File "weatherDb.py", line 53, in weatherupdate
    cursor.execute(query)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "l01" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d_type_id, swell_dir_worded, sort_order ) VALUES (l01, l02, ...
```

Im sure this is incorrect so any help and direction would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the `import` you use for the database connection.

Comment: I have updated the initial post with this info

Comment: aside from going "the long way around" on a few things (no need to assign all those L* variables), it looks fine to me.  Is it actually working?   If not, what's not working?

Comment: it throws this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weatherDb.py", line 57, in <module>
    weatherupdate(dbconnect(), getweather())
  File "weatherDb.py", line 53, in weatherupdate
    cursor.execute(query)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "l01" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d_type_id, swell_dir_worded, sort_order ) VALUES (l01, l02, ...

And I'm looking for a more simple way to write this code.

When I didn't place the 'l' in front of the variables it threw an error.

Comment: You don't need an l in front of anything... These are raw strings... You never used your actual variables. `'VALUES (l01, l02, l03...'`. Try to create a [mcve], please

Comment: Also, never name a variable `list` unless you want errors later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = """INSERT INTO weather (state_time_zone, time_zone, product_name, [SNIP]) 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, [SNIP] ) """
cursor.execute(query, (l01, l02, l03 [SNIP])
```

Comment: You're assuming all columns are strings?